# How to use value from main query in subquery (MariaDB)

Tags: database, subquery, mariadb

**Introduction**

I ask you not to get angry: StackOverflow has many topics with this title. I re-read them all, but I still have problems. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or I have an old version of DBMS ( *I have 10.1.30 MariaDB* ).

**Tables**

**1.@events_tag**

```
id,
title
```

**2.@events_tag_rel**

```
event_id,
tag_id
```

**2.@sessions**

```
id,
event_id,
date_start
```

**Query**

```
SELECT et.* FROM events_tag et
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT a_s.id FROM sessions a_s
    LEFT JOIN events_tag_rel a_etr ON a_etr.tag_id = et.id
    WHERE a_s.event_id = a_etr.event_id AND a_s.date_start >= NOW()
)
```

**Problem**

I need to use the data from the main query in subqueries.
Specifically, I'm trying to do the following: get all rows from table @**events_tag** where exist relation with table @**events_tag_rel** (by column @**tag_id**) and table @**sessions** ( by column @**event_id**).

But I get an error message:

> Unknown column 'et.id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

"from table @events_tag" -- Do you mean that the table name is a variable?  That cannot be done without constructing the query, either in your application code or in a Stored routine.  The latter would use `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, and `EXECUTE`.

The `ON` clause should specify how two tables are related.  Do not include filtering clauses.

So, change

```
FROM sessions a_s
LEFT JOIN events_tag_rel a_etr ON a_etr.tag_id = et.id
WHERE a_s.event_id = a_etr.event_id AND a_s.date_start >= NOW()
```

to

```
FROM sessions AS s
LEFT JOIN events_tag_rel AS etr  ON s.event_id = etr.event_id
WHERE  etr.tag_id = et.id
  AND  s.date_start >= NOW()
```

Furthermore, `LEFT` is probably useless in this context.

The select list is irrelevant in `EXISTS`:

```
EXISTS ( SELECT id FROM ... )
```

-->

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... )
```

Indexes that may be beneficial:

```
etr:  INDEX(tag_id, event_id)     -- in either order
s:    INDEX(date_start, event_id)
s:    INDEX(event_id, date_start)
```